# System wide browser protocol handlers?

Tags: development, browser, system

When developing an application for a Windows system, there is a registry entry you can make on the client machine that sets a 'protocol handler' in the system. In the same way that mailto links work you can have it launch your application when a specific url (ie. myapp:) is put into a web browser address bar.

This registry entry seems to work for the common browsers and does not require specific setup for each possible browser.

I have in the past, set a custom protocol handler in Firefox on Linux however... I was wondering if there was a way to do it system wide so that it would work the same for Chromium, etc as well?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not system-wide. But the Gnome registry thingy has entries for that. Use gconf-editor and edit sub entries for `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers`. See also here http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=710780&postcount=6

KDE obviously has a different URI handler database. There is also `xdg-open` worth looking into. But I'm not sure if it uses a standardized handler database, or if freedesktop.org is working on it. Sparse docs.

Personally I wish they would just use the xdg-mime (and application) database for that. There are pseudo uri/* types in it anyway. And it was somewhat more systematic if you could define handler applications and preference lists for them like with regular MIME types. </rant>

Comment: "Not system-wide. But the Gnome registry thingy has entries for that." Does that mean Yes and No at the same time?

Comment: @Sam I suspect it would affect Gnome applications only and the KDE half of your applications won't honor it.

Answer (score 6):

With GNOME 3.0 and Ubuntu 11.10, things changed compared to the accepted answer to this question.

You can find more details at "[Creating custom URL handlers in Ubuntu 11.04, 11.10, GNOME 3.0](http://web.archive.org/web/20131209005559/http://jarrpa.net/2011/10/28/creating-custom-url-handlers-in-ubuntu-11-04-11-10-gnome-3-0/)".